# jquery deferred and css3 transitions

Tags: jquery, css-transitions, jquery-deferred, chaining

For an Ajax call I have some transitions for different elements that have to be called in a specific order. When reading about jQuery Deferred I thought this is what I was looking for, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I made a simple jsfiddle to give an idea what I want to archieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/pe5Bb/1/

The problem I guess are the css3 transitions. All functions are executed from the beginning. But when I place a console.log in the transitionend callback it seems to working, but the function is still executed before.

```
function box2() {
var deferred = $.Deferred();

if ( $('#box2').hasClass('active') ) {
    $('#box2').css({opacity:0}).bind(transitionend, function(){
        console.log("css3 done");
        deferred.resolve();
        $('#box2').unbind(transitionend);
    });
 } else {
     deferred.resolve();
 }

return deferred.promise();
```

}

What I want to achieve is that I can create multiple functions (with states for the transition to new content) and I can tell in what order they should be called. In this example I work with css3 transitions that sometimes are called by adding/deleting a class. If deferred is not correct to use in this scenario I would like to hear from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is just the way you're calling done. You should be passing the function you want executed when the promise is resolved. Something like this:

```
var promise = box();
promise.done( box2 );
```

If you want to chain a bunch of calls, you could do it like this:

```
var promise = box();
promise.done(function() {
    promise = box2();
    promise.done(function() {
        scrollTo();
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/pe5Bb/2/)

Alternatively, you can use the `then` method, but you need to call it like this:

```
var promise = box();
promise.done().then( box2 ).done().then( scrollTo );
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works.
I'm still a bit confused about the .then(), because at http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/ it says: deferred.then( doneFilter [, failFilter ] [, progressFilter ] ). It's the same as done() right?

Comment: I didn't actually look at that. That way is a lot easier, but you were calling it incorrectly. See my updated answer. Btw, if you're happy with my answer, I would appreciate an upvote. :)

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer! I prefer the then, because it looks more readable, but also because I understood that then will always be called. So when an error pops up everything still goes on, which gives me a 'safe' feeling. Upvoted your answer :)

Comment: I agree - I also prefer the `then` version. I just wasn't aware of how it worked initially. So I've learned something new today too. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Paul, please note that `.done()` versus `.then()` is not just a question of readability. `.done()` unambiguously returns the input promise whereas `.then()` returns a new promise which may be of a different state (pending/resolved/rejected) and/or resolved/rejected with a different value. Thus, `.done()` (and `fail()`) are shorthand methods of more limited capability than `.then()`. If a promise were to have just one method, then it would be `.then()`.

Comment: I just realised this means you don't actually need the `.done` calls in that expression. It can simply be: 'promise.then( box2 ).then( scrollTo );'